# Will adding int still create a float number?

Tags: python, python-3.4

```
# Simple Bmi Calculator
# Weight (KG) / Height (M) then Answer / Height (m) = BMI


print("Hello, today we will calculate your Body Mass Index")

weight = input("How many kilo's do you weigh? ")  
weight = int  
height = input("What is your height in metres? ")  
height = int 
bmi = (weight / height / height)  
bmi = int

print("Thank you, your Body Mass Index is ")  
print(bmi)

input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit")
```

In the above it is likely that the height in metres will be entered as a float number (ie. 1.8) so having declared 'bmi = int' and 'height = int' will the end bmi still produce a float number if necessary?

Comment: Why not just try it and see?

Comment: `bmi = int` doesn't "force" bmi to forever be an integer or anything. It just points `bmi` at the int class, and doing it _after_ your regular assignment will just make your code break. There's no way to permanently prescribe the type of a variable name.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. If you add a floating point to an `int`, then the `int` is *promoted* to a floating point *before* the addition takes place.

Comment: Thank you! ps. I couldn't try it as we do not have access to command line at work and the online interpreters I tried wouldn't run it!

Answer (score 1):

In Python, when you perform an operation with a float and an int that would return a float, Python will automatically handle returning a float.

For instance:

```
>>> my_int = 10000
>>> my_float = 10000.10000
>>> dis.dis('my_int + my_float')
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (my_int)
              3 LOAD_NAME                1 (my_float)
              6 BINARY_ADD
              7 RETURN_VALUE
```

here we can see the bytecode instructions for adding an `int` and a `float`.

The [`BINARY_ADD`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-BINARY_ADD) operation is what we're interested in digging into.

From the [source of Python 3.4](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.4/Python/ceval.c#L1545-L1563) we can see the following operation:

```
    TARGET(BINARY_ADD) {
        PyObject *right = POP();
        PyObject *left = TOP();
        PyObject *sum;
        if (PyUnicode_CheckExact(left) &&
                 PyUnicode_CheckExact(right)) {
            sum = unicode_concatenate(left, right, f, next_instr);
            /* unicode_concatenate consumed the ref to v */
        }
        else {
            sum = PyNumber_Add(left, right);
            Py_DECREF(left);
        }
        Py_DECREF(right);
        SET_TOP(sum);
        if (sum == NULL)
            goto error;
        DISPATCH();
    }
```

And following [`PyNumber_Add`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/22f6e423198005843be05e82faa1218c2d3f37eb/Objects/abstract.c#L888-L901):

```
PyObject *
PyNumber_Add(PyObject *v, PyObject *w)
{
    PyObject *result = binary_op1(v, w, NB_SLOT(nb_add));
    if (result == Py_NotImplemented) {
        PySequenceMethods *m = v->ob_type->tp_as_sequence;
        Py_DECREF(result);
        if (m && m->sq_concat) {
            return (*m->sq_concat)(v, w);
        }
        result = binop_type_error(v, w, "+");
    }
    return result;
}
```

To [`binary_op1`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.4/Objects/abstract.c#L702-L737)

```
...
    if (v->ob_type->tp_as_number != NULL)
        slotv = NB_BINOP(v->ob_type->tp_as_number, op_slot);
...
```

at this point, we could continue tracking down those arguments passed to [`NB_BINOP`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.4/Objects/abstract.c#L687-L688) or hop over to the [documentation of the C-API](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html#c.tp_as_number).

From here, we have a pretty good reason to believe this is what we're looking for:

> This function is used by PySequence_Concat() and has the same
>   signature. It is also used by the + operator, after trying the numeric
>   addition via the nb_add slot.

We can then hop back in and look for our `nb_add` call, ending up at a [float_as_number](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.4/Objects/floatobject.c#L1787-L1788) variable.  Following that [`float_add`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.4/Objects/floatobject.c#L494-L504) will direct us to the following:

```
static PyObject *
float_add(PyObject *v, PyObject *w)
{
    double a,b;
    CONVERT_TO_DOUBLE(v, a);
    CONVERT_TO_DOUBLE(w, b);
    PyFPE_START_PROTECT("add", return 0)
    a = a + b;
    PyFPE_END_PROTECT(a)
    return PyFloat_FromDouble(a);
}
```

where we can see that the passed arguments are passed to a `CONVERT_TO_DOUBLE` function.  From here, we can see the [conversion if the value wasn't a float](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.4/Objects/floatobject.c#L235-L267):

```
#define CONVERT_TO_DOUBLE(obj, dbl)                     \
    if (PyFloat_Check(obj))                             \
        dbl = PyFloat_AS_DOUBLE(obj);                   \
    else if (convert_to_double(&(obj), &(dbl)) < 0)     \
        return obj;
```